Probability of More Than One Robbery in a District
Problem. A city with 6 districts has 6 robberies in a particular week. Assume the robberies are located randomly, with all possibilities for which robbery occurred being equally likely. What is the probability that some district had more than 1 robbery?
Source: Introduction to Probability (2nd Edition) by Joseph K. Blitzstein, Jessica Hwang
Attempt. I came across the correct answer, $1 - \frac{6!}{6^6}$, which seems plausible. However, when I first approached the problem, I reasoned as follows:
There are 6 robberies and 6 districts. Each robbery can occur in any district, so the total number of possible outcomes is $6^6$.

The probability that district $A$ gets 0 robberies is the same as assigning all 6 robberies to the other 5 districts, which gives us $5^6$ possible configurations.

The probability that district $A$ gets exactly 1 robbery involves choosing 1 robbery for district $A$ (which can be done in $\binom{6}{1} = 6$ ways), and assigning the remaining 5 robberies to the other 5 districts, giving $6 \cdot 5^5$ configurations.


$$P(\text{more than 1 robbery in A}) = 1 - \frac{5^6 + 6 \cdot 5^5}{6^6} \approx 0.2633$$
Question. Does my value represent the probability, if I predetermine a district that one specific district gets more than one robbery? Or have I misunderstood something? And the question is not concerned with one specific district, but rather with all of them?
Thanks!

You have interpreted the problem in a different manner than was intended.  Reverse-engineering the official answer, the problem was intended to be interpreted as:
What is the probability that it is not the case that each district had exactly one robbery?

Your interpretation is to interpret the phrase some district as specifically referring to an explicit district, such as district A.
Then, you are interpreting the problem as
What is the probability that district A had more than 1 robbery.

By the ambiguity of the English language, your interpretation can not be proven wrong.  However, even absent the official solution, my first guess would have been the first interpretation.
Generally, such problems come from a math book designed to teach specific concepts to the student.  My instinct would have been that the first interpretation represents the concept that the teacher intended to teach.
I emphasize that my instinct can very plausibly be wrong.  However, the official solution does support my interpretation.

Thank you so much for the clarification! I really appreciate your help.
